# How to catch page swipe event in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have developed swiping pages using UIPageViewController IOS Swift. I need to do some stuff when last page come up. How to catch page swipe event.

```html
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

  var pageViewController : UIPageViewController!
  var pageCount = 3

  func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //Return after viewcontroller
  }

  func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    //Return before viewcontroller
  }


  func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pageCount
  }


  func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method you have define may take part in this, like this way,

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let index : NSInteger = arrproductdetial.indexOfObject(viewController) as NSInteger
    if (index == arrproductdetial.count-1) {
        // Do whatever you are trying to do for last page
    }
    else if (index == arrproductdetial.count) {
        return nil; //the page after last page
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that method. It's not working properly. Sometimes that method calls when we try to swipe after the last page.

Answer (score 0):

You are just returning pageCount in

**func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int**

instead return pageCount.count as shown below:

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int 
{
    return pageCount.count
}
```

By this you can get the total count & you can get the last index as well. I guess this clears your doubt. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Your answer is wrong. "pageCount" is an integer value. There is nothing to do with that method and the event that I'm talking about.